# Using index on a row with many records but few values of data

Tags: sql

I have a column - `objectState` that only has 3 values. But this column is used in many queries. Is it going to give any performance improvement if I index this column? The table is quite big

Comment: Would depend on the queries addressing the tables. WHat is preventing you from testing it?

Comment: I wanted to have some theoretical background

Comment: It can improve the performance if, for example, one of the value is respresenting a low set of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends :-)

The dbms would usually use an index when only few records would be accessed. So if your data is like 20% for value A and 40% for value B and 40% for value C and you would select records with Value A, then that would still be 20% of the big table. Rather than scanning an index, it would usually still be better then to scan the full table instead. If, on the other hand, it is 1% for A and 99% for B and C then yes, when selecting records with value A an index would be a good thing to have.

Having said this, your dbms would have to know about the situation to make use of the index when and only when appropriate. The Oracle dbms for instance does so, provided you made sure an up-to-date  histogramm on that particular column is available in the database.

Weak dbms may get confused by an index, guessing that the mere existence of an index indicates its usefullness implicitly. They might use the index when they shouldn't.

At last some dbms are able to combine indexes. Oracle does so with so-called bitmap indexes, which are especially designed for few-value-colums. So you may ask for sex=female, age-group=young, shopping-lover=yes and rich=true. Having bitmap indexes on all of these columns would result in ADDing those bitmap indexes before accessing table records. There may only be sex = 50% female and 50% male, but although it doesn't look like an index would be helpful here, it would be in combination with other indexes.

So let me repeat: It depends :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bit Map Indexes. They give better performance if the column has low cardinality.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_bitmapped_indexes.htm